# how to pass variables to Azure Data Factory REST url's query stirng

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

i am new to Azure data factory. I have a source dataset that is linked to a REST api. The url of this API has a query string. I have an activity that copy data from REST to Database. But i have to pass different values in query string and run the same activity against different values. How can this be done in Azure Data Factory?

[image]

i kind of reached here. but how to pass the value of this "HospitalCode" ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please try something like this:

1.create a pipeline and set a variable(your HospitalCode):

```
Name:CodeArray Type:Array DEFAULT VALUE:["01","02"]
```

2.create a ForEach Activity:

```
Items:@variables('CodeArray')
```

3.create a Parameter name is `code`,type is `String`.

Setting of Linked service like this:
[image]
dynamic content:`@concat('pjjs/pls?HospitalCode=',dataset().code)`

4.Setting of Copy Activity's Source
[image]

Hope this can help you.