# pass SQL Query values to Data Factory variable as array for foreachloop

Tags: sql, arrays, azure, azure-data-factory

similar to this question [how to pass variables to Azure Data Factory REST url's query stirng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62900297/how-to-pass-variables-to-azure-data-factory-rest-urls-query-stirng)

However, I have a pipeline to query against graphapi, where I need to pass in a userid as part of the Url to get their manager to build an ActiveDirectory staff hierarchy, this is fine on an individual basis, or even as a predefined array variable where I insert["xx","xxx"] into the pipeline variable etc. My challenge is that I need to pass the results of a SQL query to be the array variable.  So, instead of defining the list of users, I need to pass into the foreach loop the results from a SQL query.

I can use a lookup to a set variable, but the url seems to be misconstructed and has extra characters added in for some reason.

returning graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7B%7B%22id%22:%22xx9e7878-bwbbb-bwbwbwr-7897-414a8e60c78c%22%7D%7D/?$expand=xxxxxx      where the "%7B%7B%22id%22:%" and "%22%7D%7D/" is all unnecessary and appears to come from the json rather than just utilising the value.
[image]

- The lookup runs the query from SQL
- The Set variable uses the lookup value's (below) to  assign to a pipeline variable as an array.

[image]

- then the foreachloop uses the variable value in the source

  @concat('users/{',item(),'}/?$expand=manager($levels=max;$select=id,displayName,userPrincipalName,createdDate)')

If anyone can suggest how to construct the array value dynamically that would be great.
I have used

```
SELECT '["'+STRING_AGG(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),t.[id]),'","')+'"]' AS id  FROM 
stage.extract_msgraphapi_users t LEFT JOIN stage.extract_msgraphapi_users s ON s.id = t.id
```

and this returns something that looks like an array ["xx","xxx"] but data factory still interpreted this as a string and not an array.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

10 minutes later:

```
@concat('users/{',item().id,'}/?$expand=manager($levels=max;$select=id,displayName,userPrincipalName,createdDate)')
```

note the reference to item().id to use the id level of the array.  Works like a dream for anyone else facing the same issue